# python fabric multiple commands

Tags: python, fabric

I'm trying to understand how fabric is working with multiple commands on one machine.
I need to run several commands on each host (thousands of hosts) and would like to know what would be best.

Using multiple runs:

```
res_1 = run(command_1)
res_2 = run(command_2)
...
...
res_n = run(command_n)
```

Or:

```
res = run(command_1 && command_2 && ... command_n)
res.splitlines()
res_1 = res[0]
res_2 = res[1]
...
...
res_n = res[n-1]
```

What I want to know is how fabric handles multiple runs, will it open multiple sessions or do all commands in the same session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of whether you use multiple `run` calls or a single `run` call with `&&`, AFAIK, fabric will open only one network connection. The difference between the two is that each new `run` executes in a different environment. For example you can try this.

```
run('ls')
run('cd /tmp/')
run('ls')
```

Both times it will show you a listing of your home directory. But if you try this

```
run('ls')
run('cd /tmp/ && ls')
```

It will show you your home directory the first time, followed by a listing of `/tmp/`. Thus if you want the state to be preserved from one command to another you should do `run('cmd1 && cmd1')` but if you are not bothered about it, you should use multiple `run` calls.

Comment: My commands are independent of each other so it is recommended to use multiple `run`s?

Comment: Yes, I would use multiple `run`s if nothing else. they are more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The important difference between those two approaches is that the first one will run all commands regardless of the exit status of former commands; the second one, however, will only execute commmand_2 if command_1 returned no error, etc. So it is up to you if you want this behaviour or the other.

Comment: Hang on a sec, unless  I am very much mistaken, if any of the commands return non zero exit states, fabric will not run the rest regardless of whether you use style 1 or style 2

Comment: I stand corrected - unless `warn_only` is set to `True`, it will behave as you said.

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is if using multiple `run` will cause more "network overhead" then using one `run` to execute multiple commands