# Python, fabric2: how to stop run command

Tags: python, fabric

Here is the sample code:

```
from fabric import Connection

host = 'servername'
ssh_user = 'user'

c = Connection(host,user = ssh_user)
result = c.run('hostname')
```

it returns in Python shell:

```
servername
```

but it does not end `run` command. 
Code waits for keyboard interrupt and brings exceptions on it:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/uname/my_python_fld/fab_test.py", line 7, in <module>
    result = c.run('hostname')
  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fabric/connection.py", line 30, in opens
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fabric/connection.py", line 586, in run
    return self._run(runner, command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/invoke/context.py", line 100, in _run
    return runner.run(command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/invoke/runners.py", line 268, in run
    return self._run_body(command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/invoke/runners.py", line 341, in _run_body
    thread.join(self._thread_timeout(target))
KeyboardInterrupt
```

So this code does not executes `pwd` command:

```
 from fabric import Connection

 host = 'servername'
 ssh_user = 'user'

 c = Connection(host,user = ssh_user)
 result = c.run('hostname')
 result2 = c.run('pwd')
```

My problem is in the fact that python script is hanging at line: "c.run('hostname')" and does not go further.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not using the standard fab env with tasks?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if that is a right way to do this but you can use`sys.exit()` and make  commands in one line, for example:

```
from fabric import Connection
import sys

...

c = Connection(host,user = ssh_user)
result = c.run('hostname && pwd')

sys.exit()
```

Also i found that `run` is execute in a different environment, for example

```
c.run('pwd')
c.run('cd /tmp')
c.run('pwd')
```

in both case it will show you the `home` directory, but if you will do one `run`

```
c.run('pwd && cd/tmp && pwd')
```

it will show you the `tmp` directory, [references from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364450/python-fabric-multiple-commands)

Answer (score 0):

It will automatically close the connection (or) you can manually close by using the object as the context manager as in the documetation  :
http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.1/api/connection.html

```
with Connection('host') as c:
    c.run('hostname')
    c.put('pwd')
```

Comment: My problem is in the fact that python script is hanging at line: "c.run('hostname')" and does not go further.